# Navigate immediately to first <p:menuitem> when <p:submenu> itself is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a dynamic [`<p:menubar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf) as follows.

```xml
<p:menubar style="position: relative; height: 30px; visibility: visible;">
    <p:submenu label="Category" icon="ui-icon-document" styleClass="mainMenu">
        <c:forEach var="row" items="#{parentMenuManagedBean.category}">
            <p:submenu label="#{row.catName}" icon="ui-icon-contact" styleClass="subMenu">
                <c:forEach var="subRow" items="#{row.subCategoryList}">
                    <p:menuitem value="#{subRow.subCatName}" url="ProductDetails.jsf?subCatId=#{subRow.subCatId}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:submenu>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

`</p:submenu>`s inside `</p:menubar>` are not clickable.

There are CSS classes which are bound to JavaScript functions. When these `<p:submenu>` are clicked, the following functions are called.

```
$(function(){
    $(".mainMenu").bind("click", function(){ alert("mainMenu was clicked"); });
});

$(function(){
    $(".subMenu").bind("click", function(){ alert("subMenu was clicked"); });
});
```

But when clicking on the inner most `<p:submenu>` both of these functions are called that should not happen.

Also how to uniquely identify each `<p:submenu>`, when they are clicked?

Is there a way to pass some value so that they can uniquely be identified like query-string appended to a URL?

Comment: This really threw me for a while. Please consider adding Primefaces to the title. I thought you were using html paragraph tags as a namespace. A little digging proved otherwise. Still there is very little in your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *But when clicking on the inner most `<p:submenu>` both of these functions are called that should not happen.*

You're victim of [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). In all browsers, when a DOM element receives an event, this is after processing on the current element propagated to all of its parents. All of their event listeners, if any, are also invoked, unless you `return false` from the current listener function, or explicitly stop the propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()` and return from the function as usual. The difference with `return false` is that the default action of the click event on the current element (going to the given URL) will still be performed.

---

> *Also how to uniquely identify each `<p:submenu>`, when they are clicked?*

The DOM element responsible for firing the event is in the listener available by `this`. You can wrap this further into a jQuery object by simply constructing it with `$()`. In case of `<p:submenu>`, that'll be a HTML `<li>` element which in turn has an `<a>` element as child.

---

> *Is there a way to pass some value so that they can uniquely be identified like query-string appended to a URL?*

Usually, you'd better explore the DOM element itself. For example, by checking the text content of the child `<a>` element.

---

All in all, here's a rewrite, note that the `event` object is available as 1st function argument:

```
$(document).on("click", ".mainMenu", function() {
    console.log("mainMenu was clicked");
});
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop event bubbling.
    var $this = $(this); // That's the <li> element.
    var $link = $this.children("a"); // That's the immediate child <a> element.
    var label = $link.text(); // You could use it to identify the submenu.
    // ...
    console.log("subMenu with label " + label + " was clicked");
});
```

*(note that I also replaced the `$(function(){})` and `$.bind()` by [`$(document).on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), this makes it safe against DOM updates on ajax requests; you don't need to re-execute the whole script then)*

---

**Update**: as per the comments, the concrete functional requirement, which wasn't clear from the initial question at all (I've improved the question title now), is to navigate to the same URL as menu's first item when the submenu itself is clicked. In that case, you'd better hook on the submenu's own `<a>` element directly by the `.subMenu>a` selector and perform a `window.location` on the URL of the menu's first `<a>` element. Here's another rewrite:

```
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu>a", function() {
    var $this = $(this); // That's the submenu's <a> element itself.
    var $link = $this.next().find("a:first"); // That's menu's first <a> element.
    var url = $link.attr("href"); // The URL of that link.
    // ...
    window.location = url; // It'll change the document immediately. No need to stop propagation.
});
```

Comment: This jQuery function is also invoked unnecessarily, when the inner most `<p:menuitem>` (the only line inside `<c:forEach>`) is clicked.

Comment: I understood that this was actually your requirement (because the submenu already acts on hover instead of click and therefore it made no sense to listen explicitly on the click event in order to know if it was opened or not). Well, attach a new click listener on `<p:menuitem>` with `event.stopPropagation()`. Alternatively, check if `event.target` is the same as `this`. See also the article behind the "event bubbling" link. Regardless, depending on the concrete functional requirement which wasn't exactly clear from the question, there may be a better solution than this all.

Comment: The requirement is only to navigate to another page with an `id` (`Long` type) as a query-string parameter, when an item of `<p:submenu >` is clicked exactly as done by `<p:menuitem>`.

Comment: Got it. To which URL exactly? That of the first child item?

Comment: Yes it is the first child item and the URL could be anything like `Category.jsf?id=10` (`Category.jsf` is always stable. Only the `id` varies across URLs. The `id`, in this case could be referenced by `#{row.catId`).

Comment: Updated answer. In future questions always try to state the concrete functional requirement directly.

Comment: @BalusC please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013593/richselect-bean-property-doesnt-update-during-manual-input-mode). This has been bugging me for days now. I would really appreciate if you provide some insights.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use stopPropagation

```
$( ".subMenu").click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Do something
});
```

This will stop the parent to be notified of the event.

Check this http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/